# Build hash from tree-like structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, hash

I have model called `Project`, which can have any amount of children, and children(child) can have any amount of children. Basically i'm using gem
https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set to achieve this(tree-kind structure)
I want to build hash like `hash[child.id] = child.name` in order of parentship.
For ex. i have 3 projects(1,2,3), project#2 is child of project#1, project#3 and project#1 are roots.
In result i want hash, that will look like `{1=> name1, 2=> name2, 3=> name3}`

I know this needs to be done recursively, but i'm stuck with following code

```
def self.build_tree_of_projects(project)
    hash = {}
    project.children.each do |child|
      hash[child.id] = "#{'&nbsp;&nbsp;' * child.level +  '»' + '&nbsp;'}#{child.try(:name)}"
      next unless child.children.present?
      hash.merge(self.build_tree_of_projects(child)) if child.children.present?
    end
    hash
  end
```

It just return me hash with 1 pair, when should be ~5. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `hash.merge` [does not change the hash in-place](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge). Replace your call to `hash.merge` with a call to `hash.merge!` and it should work.

Comment: damn, exactly, missed this thing. Thanks